# Not able to connect to Azure SQL Server via Dremio

Tags: azure-sql-server, dremio

We were not able add Azure SQL Server as external data source in Dremio. We have disabled the firewall to allow all access (at the Azure SQL Server end) to connect to Azure SQL Server, but it was still throwing an error and it was not able to connect from Dremio.

Please let us know if we will need to configure a firewall on route from the Dremio server end to connect to the Azure SQL Server.

Error output:

```
> Error : Could not connect to intake-dev,   
> check your JDBC connection information and credentials.
```

Note: We have checked that the credentials passed are accurate, and we were able to connect from SSMS using these.

Comment: Az SQL Server connection can be added in Dremio . We had to open the firewall port from src: dremio to connect dest: - az sql server .

Comment: Could you please give more info on opening firewall port from source (Dremio)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Dremio does not support Azure SQL Server as a source.
Check this [post](https://community.dremio.com/t/cant-connect-azure-sql-server-as-data-source/4704) on dremio community.

Comment: The response on the post is as of 2019. Is this response still valid?

Comment: I hope so because there is no supported document available from Dremio and Microsoft. There is proper documentation available for Dremio and Azure Data Lake Storage(ADLS) integration, but there is nothing for Azure SQL Server.